# How to white list a single controller or action when web.config restricts entire application by role by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, authorize-attribute

By default in my application, I have denied all users who are not in a particular active directory group, which works correctly.

Here is the snippet of the relevant part of my web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="domainXXX\GroupXXX" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/Unauthorised" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Now I would like the actions in a single controller to be accessible without authorisation. I have tried to add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to my controller, but I still must be logged in to access these actions. Is it not possible to mix these approaches? i.e. restrict role in web.config and allow anonymous users via the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this. Instead of restricting the role globally in web.config, the `[AuthorizeAttribute]` is now applied to all routes via in `FilterConfig.cs`. When added like this in code (and not in config) then the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute seems to work as expected and allow authenticated access when it is annotated over a controller or action.

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
var authorizeAttribute = new AuthorizeAttribute
{
    Roles = "domainXXX\GroupXXX"
};

filters.Add(authorizeAttribute);
```

This allows control at the controller level rather than having to hard code URIs. So the URI of a controller can change and the attribute will still work as expected. In this was configured in `web.config`, you would have to remember to change the URI there.

Blogged here: http://spencerooni.github.io/2015/07/12/authenticating-and-authorizing-users-from-active-directory-in-asp.net.html

Answer (score 1):

This used to work well with webforms but never tested the same with MVC but I believe it should work:

```
<location path="~/xyzPage">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Setting a separate authorization rule for a particular web location should work for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I found another way around it (see my answer) which means I don't have to specify a path and can keep the annotation on the controller.